# FFmpeg memory usage

Tags: video, memory, ffmpeg, h.264

I'm using the latest FFmpeg library to blend together 4 different input videos. 
To accomplish it I do some basic "filter_complex" operations for video and "amix" for audios.
After about 1 minute of processing data, the process is being killed with signal "SIGKILL". Probably out of memory causes this error. To check current memory usage I run "top" tool which shows up in the moment of a crash that 90% of all available memory is allocated.

My kubernetes pool has available 30GB RAM and 8CPU. It looks strange because FullHd process consumes 30GB memory in 1 minute of work.

I'm wonder is any way to optimize or limit memory usage.

FFmpeg version: 4.0.2
system: Linux
encoder: h.264
format: 1920x1080

**FFmpeg output**
https://gist.github.com/mbutan/51f832a99d0edf0b09af934d1934971e

**Code snippet:**

```
          ffmpeg \
  -i /tmp/a3ddcc11-9819-4bef-8e8d-156342aa68df.mp4 \
  -itsoffset 3 -i /tmp/c87d7e8f-c9e7-4fbe-b845-e6cd6d6ac7bb.mp4 \
  -itsoffset 3.199 -i /tmp/250cb6e8-8daf-4c5b-88b3-4b6cfb02834b.mp4 \
  -itsoffset 37.52 -i /tmp/24e466e1-c1e0-4797-b88a-09e2a9f5f673.mp4 \
  -itsoffset 68.04 -i /tmp/3e0e0e62-82e4-4d6a-881a-119d7c72cf9f.mp4 \
  -itsoffset 415.188 -i /tmp/02ca91d5-f0c1-4140-ba12-fa445f09ddf6.mp4 \
  -i /tmp/1.png -i /tmp/2.png -i /tmp/3.png \
  -y -filter_complex pad=1920:1080:color=black [base];[6] scale=1920:1080 [background];\
  [0:v] scale=1740:980,pad=1740:980:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2 [main_0];[base][main_0] overlay=90:50:enable=between'(t,0,3)' [tmp_4];\
  [1:v] scale=1740:980,pad=1740:980:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2 [main_1];[tmp_4][main_1] overlay=90:50:enable=between'(t,3,29.5)' [tmp_6];\
  [2:v] scale=1740:980,pad=1740:980:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2 [main_2];[tmp_6][main_2] overlay=90:50:enable=between'(t,29.5,37.5)' [tmp_8];\
  [3:v] scale=1740:980,pad=1740:980:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2 [main_3];[tmp_8][main_3] overlay=90:50:enable=between'(t,37.5,58)' [tmp_10];\
  [2:v] scale=1740:980,pad=1740:980:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2 [main_4];[tmp_10][main_4] overlay=90:50:enable=between'(t,58,68)' [tmp_12];\
  [4:v] scale=1740:980,pad=1740:980:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2 [main_5];[tmp_12][main_5] overlay=90:50:enable=between'(t,68,414.5)' [tmp_14];\
  [2:v] scale=1740:980,pad=1740:980:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2 [main_6];[tmp_14][main_6] overlay=90:50:enable=between'(t,414.5,415.5)' [tmp_16];\
  [5:v] scale=1740:980,pad=1740:980:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2 [main_7];[tmp_16][main_7] overlay=90:50:enable=between'(t,415.5,416.248)' [tmp_18];\
  [tmp_18][background] overlay=0:0 [tmp_19];[7] scale=306.66666666666663:190[user_shadow_0];\
  [tmp_19][user_shadow_0] overlay=807:842:enable=between'(t,3.199,30.833)' [shadow_output_0_0];\
  [2:v] scale=266.66666666666663:150:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease, pad=266.66666666666663:150:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:black [user_0_3199];\
  [shadow_output_0_0][user_0_3199] overlay=827:862:enable=between'(t,3.199,30.833)' [tmp_23];[7] scale=306.66666666666663:190[user_shadow_0];\
  [tmp_23][user_shadow_0] overlay=807:842:enable=between'(t,37.52,57.965)' [shadow_output_0_0];\
  [2:v] scale=266.66666666666663:150:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease, pad=266.66666666666663:150:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:black [user_0_37520];\
  [shadow_output_0_0][user_0_37520] overlay=827:862:enable=between'(t,37.52,57.965)' [tmp_27];[7] scale=306.66666666666663:190[user_shadow_0];\
  [tmp_27][user_shadow_0] overlay=807:842:enable=between'(t,68.04,414.648)' [shadow_output_0_0];\
  [2:v] scale=266.66666666666663:150:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease, pad=266.66666666666663:150:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:black [user_0_68040];\
  [shadow_output_0_0][user_0_68040] overlay=827:862:enable=between'(t,68.04,414.648)' [tmp_31];\
  [0:v] scale=1920:1080 [intro];[tmp_31][intro] overlay=0:0:enable=between'(t,0,3.25)' [tmp_32];\
  [tmp_32][0:v] overlay='if(lte((t-3.25)*18432,w),(t-3.25)*18432,w)':0:enable=between'(t,3.25,4.45)' [tmp_33];[5:v] scale=1920:1080 [end];\
  [tmp_33][end] overlay=0:0:enable=between'(t,414.75,418)' [tmp_34];\
  [tmp_34][5:v] overlay='if(lte((t-418)*18432,w),(t-418)*18432,w)':0:enable=between'(t,418,419.2)' [outVideo];\
  [0:a]adelay=1|1 [audio_0];\
  [1:a]adelay=3001|3001 [audio_1];\
  [2:a]adelay=3200|3200 [audio_2];\
  [3:a]adelay=37521|37521 [audio_3];\
  [4:a]adelay=68041|68041 [audio_4];\
  [5:a]adelay=415189|415189 [audio_5];\
  [audio_0][audio_1][audio_2][audio_3][audio_4][audio_5] amix=inputs=6:duration=longest \
  [outAudio] -map [outVideo] -map [outAudio] -framerate 30 -g 60 -video_size 1920x1080 -vcodec libx264 -acodec libfdk_aac -profile:a aac_he -b:a 192k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 -threads 0 -strict experimental -preset fast /tmp/53a89b44-fd56-4c5b-adb9-a5695d52e5d2_output.mp4
```

Comment: please post ffmpeg command

Comment: Do you blend 4 video for real time display, or for encoding them ?

Comment: @mofo77for encoding

Comment: @Harry attached ffmpeg code.

Comment: i guess itsoffset is your Problem, not sure if it is intended to buffer that much amount of data.

Comment: how to delay playing the video in another way? @Harry

Comment: hmmm i don't see a direct way but i am not 100% expert ;-) possibly generate black Video from -i /dev/Zero for concat with the actual source.. But first make sure this is your Problem by just removing itsoffset and watch Memory consumption...

Comment: Please also post ffmpeg output, specifically if some of filtergraphs reports too much queued frames in buffer.

Comment: @PaulB.Mahol attached output in gist

Comment: I sort of reproduced memory problems, and not using -itsoffset fixed it. Try using setpts & asetpts instead

Comment: @PaulB.Mahol unfortunately, it didn't help

Comment: Well the issue got away if I processed video and audio separately. You can mux them together later.

Comment: then post-processing gets really complicated what increases the preparation time.

Answer (score 1):

The Memory leak issue has been resolved with the latest Master branch, thanks a lot to Paul B. Mahol for his commitment.
This commit fixes mentioned problem: [commit](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commit;h=bd02a6d7ed90ea1e13ff11450a8701dd1ab842fd)